# javascript .match function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the following javascript .match script to allow telephone numbers in form submit

```
var number = jQuery('#phone-number').val();

if ((number.match(/(\d)\1\1\1\1\1/))
          || (number.match(/(\d)(\d)\1\2\1\2\1\2/))
          || (number.match(/123456|234567|345678|456789|567890|987654|876543|765432|654321|543210/))
          || (!number.match(/^(0\d{8,10})?$/))) {
        alert("Please supply a valid phone number");
        return false;
}
```

Currently, it doesnt allow a SPACE between numbers.. I'm no good at regex and was wondering if someone could tell me how I allow a SPACE between any number using the script above?

thanks
Craig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly, but:

```
 if ((number.match(/(\d)\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1\s*/))
              || (number.match(/(\d)\s*(\d)\s*\1\s*\2\s*\1\s*\2\s*\1\s*\2\s*/))
              || (number.match(/123456|234567|345678|456789|567890|987654|876543|765432|654321|543210/))
              || (!number.match(/^(0(?:\s*\d\s*){8,10})?$/))) {
            alert("Please supply a valid phone number");
            return false;
    }
```

For 1 space only replace \s* with \s?

Comment: I only want to allow 1 SPACE in total between all numbers.

Comment: then replace \s* with \s?

Comment: it also allows for too few digits.. ie 01235 is allowd.  Uk numbers are from 9 - 11 digits

Comment: It is allowed because that is what one of your conditions (your first) are. It is not about space. I did only change the spaces, not modified your original regex.

Comment: before your if check, put another if above in case your string is too short: `if(/^\s*(?:\s*\d\s*){1,8}\s*$/gi.test(number)){return false}` this will terminate the function when you have less than 9 numbers. Adjust it from {1,8} as you want

Comment: how do I add a maximum amount of numbers allowed in this If statement?

Comment: switch the regex in if in the above comment to `/^\s*(?:\s*\d\s*){1,8}$|^\s*(?:\s*\d\s*){10,}\s*$/gi` The part before "|" will set the lower count (too few), the part after "|" will match upper count (too many)

Comment: your answer above "\s*" causes "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags"

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. I just wrote in console: `/^\s*(?:\s*\d\s*){1,8}$|^\s*(?:\s*\d\s*){10,}\s*$/gi.test("1 1 1 1 1 1")` and got "true"

Comment: I mean this code, its giving syntax error - 
 if ((number.match(/(\d)\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1/\s*))
              || (number.match(/(\d)\s*(\d)\s*\1\s*\2\s*\1\s*\2\s*\1\s*\2/\s*))
              || (number.match(/123456|234567|345678|456789|567890|987654|876543|765432|654321|543210/))
              || (!number.match(/^(0(?:\s*\d\s*){8,10})?$/))) {
            alert("Please supply a valid phone number");
            return false;
    }

Comment: \s* was misplaced before the closing "/". I updated the main answer

Comment: Just a sec,I saw another one there. Ok, updated now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify any number of spaces between each character, you can use `\s*`.

`\s` stands for whitespace character and `*` for any number of those

E.g.

```
\s*(\d)\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1\s*
```

```js
const regex = /\s*(\d)\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1\s*\1\s*/;

const tel1 = '111111';
const tel2 = ' 1 1 1 1   1 1';
console.log(regex.test(tel1));
console.log(regex.test(tel2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all spaces from a string with

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Then you can use your existing code.

Comment: no, I dont want to REMOVE all spaces.. I want to ALLOW spaces in the phone number using the script above.

Comment: @JosephReeve what did you change?

Comment: You just check your existing regex on the number-string without spaces. If the check fails, your return False. If not, you use the original number-string (with spaces). Or did I miss something?

Comment: Or you put \s* at each and every position in your regex-string, as Matus answered. It kinda depends on your taste, but I prefer my solution because the regex is far more readable without millions of \s* in it.